# Trying to get CloudFront to work with Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, csv, cloudfront-cdn

My problem is that I upload all my products using the import function on Magento, it is easier to upload products in bulk using a CSV file in this way.

I have a field for images, and I upload all my images first on S3 bucket which I have set my origin in Cloudfront to fetch these images. So everything is setup fine regarding displaying the images on CloudFront if I add the absolute URL of the image path in the browser my image shows fine, so this is the image URL I add to my CSV file for Magento to find and upload my images according to each product.

So once I upload my products via a CSV file Magento fetches my images from S3 bucket and adds them to Magento folders. Now I have uploaded my images but they not showing from CloudFront rather from the same server as Magento. The next step I create the same folder structure as Magento for my images and CSS files and upload all the images and files to S3 bucket. Then I go to Magento backend and change the Base Site/Media URL to CloudFront, this now fetches my images and files from Cloudfront.

Now my file name for the images once fetched has the CloudFront URL I added in my backend and adds the absolute URL also as a filename from my CSV file I added, so the filename is terribly long and looks cumbersome. 
Also now I have a duplication of images on my Magento server and S3 and every time I want to upload more images I have to copy all the folders and files from Magento server to S3, this is a long tedious process.

Please advice what I am doing wrong and if there is a way I can do this better and more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I am not sure what is going wrong at your end but I will suggest you to use this extension (https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3) to achieve the same for Magento2. This extension will upload all your media stuff directly to S3 bucket instead of uploading on your server and then copy to S3 bucket. I have also used the same extension for Magento 1.9.x (https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3) and this is working fine.

Try this and share your experience with me.